# sha1WithRSAEncryption in Python

Tags: python, xml, sha1

Can someone recommend a library for calculating SHA1WithRSAEncryption in Python?

Context: I'm trying to do some message authentication. I've looked at PyXMLDSig, but it seemed to expect the certificates as separate files. As a first step to better understanding the problem space, I wanted to calculate the digest values "by hand".

I've looked around and seen Java implementations, but not Python ones. (Jython isn't really an option for my environment.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at M2Crypto, it's probably the best and most complete crypto library for Python.